How to make spring JPA auto conversion similar to mybatis
In mybatis : Column conversion will happen automatically for columns in select:
Ex : I have a select query with only 2 columns. but i want to map this 2 columns into en entity which is common to a table.
Customer entity has 20 columns : ID, Age, Name, Dept, etc
In one query i have used select ID, other query select Dept, Name
Without any converted the selected columns will populated in Customer Entity other fields will set to either default or null.
How to do this Spring JPA or Hibernate ? Wihtout creating multiple Entityclass or Constructor
I tried many solutions. SqlMapping Annoation. But nothing works. Please help

I know nothing about mybats and I am not sure if my suggestion will go against your desire of going "without creating multiple entityclasses", but you might want to take a look on Spring Data JPA Projections.

My usecase is in mybatis using only one POJO class lets say Customer.java. We can have 100 select queries with different "select columns".

select id, name to Customer POJO
select age, dept to Customer POJO
Mybatis will automatically map the mentioned columns with the POJO remaining columns will set to NULL or default.

